# VS2012 migration "HasTrailingSlash" issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, migration, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to migrate a VS 2005 project to VS 2012. But it reports the following error.

> The "HasTrailingSlash" function only accepts a scalar value, but its
>   argument "$(IntDir)" evaluates to
>   "C:\Users\Mahesh\HelloWorld_obj\DebugW7-Win32;\" which is not a
>   scalar value.  C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.targets

I understand its a string literal and not a scalar value. But how to resolve the issue. Can anyone please share your ideas. Googling didn't help much.

Comment: Get rid of that ; semicolon first.

Comment: @HansPassant To which file I need to look into to modify it?

Comment: Your project file.  In the IDE it is the General + Intermediate Directory setting.

Comment: Thanks. I think I found the cause of it. Trying to resolve :)

Comment: @HansPassant Please see the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Failed attempt : Though changing the delimeter to `/` from `;` for the macro serving as `intermediate directory` in the property sheet did not work.

Success: I opened the property sheet in Notepad and removed the following lines for the user macro "ObjOut" which serves as an intermediate directory for my project.

```
InheritsFromParent="true"
Delimiter=";"
```

The same can be achieved via IDE as well when `"Macro inherits from parent property sheets"` is unchecked for the macro.

Hope this is useful to someone in future. I posted the same on [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/03056705-ef73-45fe-87ff-12960f4aeb0d/) as well.